# Is it possible to implement a Recommender System without having a ratings/previous purchases similar data?

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system, unsupervised-learning

I'm trying to implement a recommender system for a website that hosts a wide variety of software and you can search the website to find what you need. The need is to implement a recommender system to better recommend software to the users except that there is no ratings system and users don't really buy the software from the website...

A first approach would be like this: let's imagine a user clicks on software **A**, we can search for the most clicked software by all the users who also clicked on software **A**. But this would lack meaning since these users that clicked on software **A** may just search the category of this software and would click on the first suggestion from a list that may be sorted alphabetically.

Also, the users don't really interact with the software. They can't bookmark it or post a comment so we can't just take these actions and give them a weight to simulate a rating system.

I don't really find ideas about solving this issue and I don't have any experience with user tracking data so any idea would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In the complete absence of user feedback, you can still build a (non-personalized) recommender system based on the products' descriptive features, e.g. by employing some distance metric.

In your case, there are at least two behavioral signals: clicks and search terms. Both can be used to personalize recommendations. I would start with getting familiar with *session-based recommendations*, which take into account user's actions in the context of the current session, and refine the recommendations incrementally (a kNN algorithm would be a good starting point).

Comment: Thank you for your answer I think that'll help a lot. While searching I also found reinforcement learning based recommender systems. What do you think about them?

Comment: I think that multi-arm bandits in particular are very useful in reinforcement learning tasks. If you have access to user features, you can try a contextual bandit which chooses products to recommend based on a user's feature vector.

Comment: Thank you for your help !